# Latexmk fails after max runs due to cyclic author replacement in citation

Tags: biblatex, pdftex, biber, latexmk

I've got the following problem. Running `latexmk` on my project fails because files are not getting stable after the maximum number of runs:

```
Running 'pdflatex  -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -recorder  "main.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'main.bbl'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main.pdf'
Latexmk: Found biber source file(s) [Literaturliste.bib main.bcf]
Rule 'pdflatex': File changes, etc:
   Changed files, or newly in use since previous run(s):
      'main.aux'
Latexmk: Maximum runs of pdflatex reached without getting stable files
```

This is caused by a citation that changes in a cyclic way. In state A, the author's name in the citation is replaced with "ebd", as the author is the same as the one in the previous cite on the same page. But at the same time, the citation flows to the next page.

[image: State A. Author replaced, but flows on next page.]

Now the citation with "ebd" isn't on a page anymore where the author was already mentioned. Therefore, after invoking `pdflatex` again, it is replaced once again with the author's name, which causes it again to flow to the previous page (state B).

[image: State B.]

After invoking `pdflatex` again, the citation moves back into state A. As the main.aux always changes, `latexmk` never finishes. Between the two states, the only change is this one in the `main.aux`:

[image]

**Has anyone got an idea how I can get rid of this?**

PS: Sorry, I couldn't isolate this into an MWE yet. Here is a minimal excerpt from my configuration, feel free to ask for additional information I should provide.

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[%
    backend=biber,%
    sorting=nyt,%
    style=ext-authoryear-ibid,%
    hyperref=auto,%
    maxnames=2,%
    innamebeforetitle=true,%
    innameidem=true,%
]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{:~}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}
```

Comment: probably you can run it to that point then add `\nofiles` so it stops writing aux files. Make sure to remove that command if you make edits, so you get updated files.

Comment: See also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/109, I don't think there came anything of it, though.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Using `\nofiles` stops the cycle, but it doesn't bring the document in a "valid" state, only does a last step between those two states.

Comment: @katexochen define "valid". You can stop it at the point it uses a full name, or the abbreviation depending how may runs before adding `\nofiles` but then whichever you choose it keeps that even if page break moves. Not sure what other choices there are other than those two?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle "valid": either 1) the citation is on the previous page and uses the abbreviation or 2) it is on the next page and uses the full name. The two states I encounter at the moment are invalid in this sense.

Comment: hmm of course I don't have the files to check:-) If absolutely necessary, after adding `\nofiles` you could edit the aux file by hand to force the choice to whatever you need. I would have thought one of the two oscillating aux files would be OK but running the algorithm in my head does leave room for error...

Comment: For anyone who is interested, the already-mentioned link https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/109 contains a MWE. The probability of the problem occurring is very small for any one citation, so a short MWE is contrived.  But in a big document the small probability must be multiplied by the number of citations.

Comment: The difficulty is that given TeX's page breaking algorithm, the requirements on the format of the citation are inconsistent.   One way to fix the problem is to prevent a page break (and unfortunately also a line break) by, for example, `\mbox{\autocite{foo}}`.  I'd only do this in a final version of the document, since the problem often disappears with even a minor rewording of the text of the document.

Comment: @JohnCollins `\mbox` works great as workaround to get a valid result in the final version, thanks!

Comment: Would be great to also have a workaround for `latexmk` not to exit with an error code when this situation occurs during the writing process, especially regarding IDE and CI integration...